# Does special theory of relativity limit velocity to speed of light, but general theory not?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, faster-than-light

In fact I don't even need to spin around, just being on the spinning earth is good enough.

Suppose I look out into space at the nearest star, Alpha Centauri, approximately 4 light years away. Working from the gravity accelerated frame of reference that I occupy on the surface of the earth, th star appears to go around the earth in one day, travelling a distance of $2*\pi*4$ or roughly 24 light years - in a day.

What I am really getting at, is that relativity tells us all frames of reference are valid, as well as that things cannot travel faster than light. But from this particular frame of reference, that would not seem to be true.

This accelerated, rotating frame of reference can be described as equivalent to some other frame by general relativity, so I think it is valid to look at it from different frames of reference.

Does this imply that the theory of general relativity does not place an upper bound of the speed of light on velocity?

Comment: Questions are free - if you want to ask two, do ask two. Please don't stuff a two questions in one. People won't notice that your second question is unanswered after I answered your first question.

Comment: Ok, I'll chop off Q2 into its own question.

Comment: I do think that this is a good question. It is not true that only non-accelerating frames of reference are on the same footing. According to general relativity EVERY frame is on the same footing. My quick reply would be: are you sure that you can spin faster and faster, without YOU breaking the speed of light limit?

Comment: But as you noticed, even given the usual angular speed of the Earth, the apparent velocity already exceeds the speed of light - this is why quick answers never work.

Comment: Yes, I thought the general theory extends to accelerated frames - does this mean that the special theory implies nothing can exceed the speed of light, but that the general theory does not imply this limitation?

Comment: Here I have a yardstick 24 light years long.  The center is at the point marked 6.  In a fraction of a second, I break the yardstick at the point marked 18, and now the center is at the point marked 9.  The center has moved 3 light years in a fraction of a second.   Did I just violate special relativity?

Answer (score 2):

All *non-accelerating non-rotating* frames of reference are equal, so that straight away explains the apparent violation.

In general, *apparent* motion can easily exceed the speed of light. For instance, if I'd shine a laser on the moon, I could make that spot move over the lunar surface quite quickly simply by rotating the laser here on earth. If I rotate the laser fast enough, the spot will in fact move faster than the speed of light. This is possible because that laser light spot isn't a physical object; it's the effect of the lasers photons being reflected. And as I rotate the laser, the photons leave earth in different directions. The spot that I see move therefore consists of reflected photons, bu those are *different* photons over time. Each individual photon is still bound by the speed of light.

Answer (score 1):

General Relativity is build such that it reduces to special relativity locally. That means that if you perform an experiment locally no particle or wave can exceed the speed of light. As you have pointed out, globally this is no longer true. For example in inflation, spacetime is created at such as speed that spacetime points that were initially causally connected are no longer connected - they must have receded at a speed larger than the speed of light. (By the way, this is one way to resolve the [horizon problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon_problem)).

In principle this is not surprising if you have already heard about cosmology. The 'recessional speed' of galaxies is proportional to their distance, and thus, at some distance their speed exceeds the speed of light. To be a bit more precise (and this is way I wrote 'speed' in quotation marks): Keep in mind that velocity can be only compared locally in General Relativity, since it is a curved manifold. There is no unique way to compare velocities of two objects that are not at the same spacetime point. (There is the standard example of [parallel transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport) on a sphere).